# C++ ifstream read offset range

Tags: c++

I work an file, in this file content: "hello_READHERE_guys". How to read "READHERE" position only?

I trying this code and fail:

```
std::ifstream is("test.txt");

if (is.good())
{
    is.seekg(5, ios::end); // step from end "_guys"
    is.seekg(6, ios::beg); // step from start "hello_"

    std::string data;

    while (is >> data) {}

    std::cout << data << std::endl; // output "READHERE_guys" fail.
}
```

Comment: You should probably read the documentation for `seekg`. It does not define a "range", it only moves the read position.

Comment: I readed docs, and trying not working. Help me please.

Comment: Windows api ReadFile function giving nNumberOfBytesToRead. for ifstream What should I do?

Comment: PointerToRawData and SizeOfRawData size's there.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here, are you suppose to read and parse data based on hello_ and _guys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The seekg function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) does only *set the position of the next character to be extracted from the input stream*. It cannot set a "limit" to stop. So the following line:

```
is.seekg(5, ios::end); // step from end "_guys"
```

Is incorrect. A use of seekg with `ios::end` won't set a limit.

Your other use is correct however. If you want to read just a specific block of data, and if you know precisely the size of this block of data (the precise size of the string "READHERE"), you can use the [istream::read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) function in order to read it:

```
std::ifstream is("test.txt");

if (is.good())
{
    is.seekg(5, ios::end); // step from end "_guys"


    std::string data(sizeof("READHERE"), '\0'); // Initialize a string of the appropriate length.

    is.read(&data[0], sizeof("READHERE")); // Read the word and store it into the string.

    std::cout << data << std::endl; // output "READHERE".
}
```

Comment: Why not resize `data` and read into it directly? No need for the round-trip through `buffer` and C-like functions. In fact you're not using `data` at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are right, my previous solution was too C-style. I replaced it by use of `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

When you first call `seekg` it sets a 'cursor' in file in specified position. Then after you call `seekg` second time it sets that 'curson' in another position (after 'head_' now) but it doesn't care about previous call so it wouldn't read as you suppose.

One solution is as folows:

```
std::string data;
is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '_');
std::getline(is, data, '_');
```

[`std::ifstream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is used to skip everything until and including first occurence of '_'. Now [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reads everything from that file (after skipped part of course) till it encounters characher-delimiter that is provided as third argument (`'_'`) so it would read exactly what you want.